# What is the best approach for renewing/recreating a Google push notification channel before expiration

Tags: php, push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using a Google Calendar Push Notifications in my web app. Currently, I'm able to create a notification channel with a unique id and resource id. I'm also receiving a push notification whenever any event added/edited in the calendar.

What would be the best approach for renewing/recreating channel just before expiry time with users presence? In the Database, I'm saving user id , channel id, expiry time, current channel creation time.

Comment: Curious to find an answer so I added a bounty. A solution might be to save the expiry times. In doing so, I would be polling my db every minute, and if expired, send the watch request. However, within that 1 minute window, a user may update their calendar with the watch status turned off because the watch has not been renewed :(

Comment: Looks legit edit, I'm worried about the entire question suitability, but in the future, maybe you should integrate your minor informative edits so that they make contextual sense instead of appending them.

Comment: CAN you renew the notification channel PRIOR to the expiration time?

Comment: @AaronHall what do you mean by question suitability? Too general with best approach?

Answer (score 3):

The [Google Push Notifications API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#renew) says that you *can* renew before the expiration; indeed, they implicitly recommend doing so:

"Currently there is no automatic way to renew a notification channel. When a channel is close to its expiration, you must create a new one by calling the watch method. As always, you must use a unique value for the id property of the new channel. Note that there is likely to be an "overlap" period of time when the two notification channels for the same resource are active."

Does PHP offer no timer mechanism? In Java, I'd note the expiration time and set a `Timer` or similar to renew the notification just before hand - no need to poll the DB repeatedly for an expiration date that's not going to change...

Comment: I didn't consider using a new id as renewing since you are using a new id and you gain an extra channel. And if you use the same ID, you end up with this error: '{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"push","reason":"channelIdNotUnique","message":"Channel id 530f6074bdab467e7e000001 not unique"}],"code":400,"message":"Channel id 530f6074bdab467e7e000001 not unique"}}'. But receiving 2 push notifications is a better case than missing the push notification.

Comment: @Chandrew You can always stop the old notification after creating the new one "watch". https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#stopping-notifications